# How can I accomplish this regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I want a regex that matches "cell" values from A-J rows to 1-10 columns.

For example it should match `A10`, `A1`, `E9`

It should not match `A100`, `A30`, `P7`, `A01`

By the time being, I came up with this regex:
`(?:[ABCDEFGHIJabcdefghij][123456789](?![123456789]))(?<=1)(0)?`

The only case where it fails is when you give it a `A100` cell, it matches the first two characters when in reality it should not return a match.

EDIT:
Playing around a little bit, I wrote:
(?<!\S)[ABCDEFGHIJabcdefghij]123456789((?<=1)(0))?(?!\S)

Which seems to work for even most cases. I´m still open to suggestions on how to improve it / write it more elegantly.

Comment: Like this? `\b[A-Ja-j](?:10|[1-9])\b` https://regex101.com/r/4CImxU/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the pattern using a ranges. Then you could match either 10 or 1-9 using an alternation instead of using `(?<=1)(0)?` to match 10.

To prevent the partial match, you can use word boundaries.

```
\b[A-Ja-j](?:10|[1-9])\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[A-Ja-j]` Match either chars in a range from A-J or a-j
- `(?:10|[1-9])` Match either 10 or a single digit 1-9
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4CImxU/1)

---

With whitespace boundaries on the left and right:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Ja-j](?:10|[1-9])(?!\S)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that solution is clever and exactly what I was looking for, didn´t know about /b.